# Square root of a matrix by looking at the eigenspaces

Tags: matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

A problem that is well known in linear algebra is the existence of square root of a matrix, where square root of matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb F)$ is defined to be $K \in M_n(\mathbb F)$ such that $K^2=A$

I looked in different places for a proof of this theorem and could not find any.

> Let $A$ be a matrix over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ and
>   let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_m$ be **distinct** eigenvalues
>   of $A$, if $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ then exists a square
>   matrix.

I tried finding a counter-example but couldn't, so I tried proving it, I could prove that for eigenspace, the matrix $A|_{V_{\lambda_i}}$ has a square root by looking at the Taylor polynomial $\sqrt{1+x}$ of the matrix $J=
\lambda I+N$ and since $0$ is not an eigenvalue, the Taylor series converges since $N$ is nilpotent then the series trivially converges (as it becomes $0$ at some index $k\le n$)

I couldn't although prove that if the restriction of every eigenspace of $A$ has a square root then $A$ itself has a square root.